# Is there some way to detect or prevent multiple subscribers to a Flux or Mono?

Tags: project-reactor

If you want to have **several subscribers** to a publisher and you want all of them to receive the published item, you should use a [ConnectableFlux](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-broadcast-multiple-subscribers-connectableflux).

However, when you use a normal Flux and several subscribers subscribe, **only one of them will receive the published item**. The normal Flux was likely designed to have a single subscriber.

It has happened to me that several subscribers have subscribed by accident. Is there a way to **detect** or **prevent** more than one subscriber to a given Flux or Mono?